# Warning missing files from Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I needed to remove a library of my project that was added with cocoa pods.

To achieve this, took its name from the pod´s file and ran the command **pod update**.

The library was removed, however xcode show me warnings about the missing files.

[image]

How can i remove this?

Comment: Those warnings should disappear once you have committed the changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally discovered the error. 
It doesn´t have to be anything directly with **cocoapods**, but with my SVN repository. 
These files were added to my svn repository, soo after remove them through the cocoapods, svn still seeking those same files. 
The solution was to manually remove them with:  `svn delete "nameFile"`

Comment: But when I tried to delete manually it shows file does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. Sigh. In my case this was Xcode 8 screwing up. After I checked all changes into git , these warnings went away.

It's kind of infuriating because I generally don't check in code that has a ton of warnings... so it took me a while to find this.